# HTTP post a XML to the server Store Sever Response in PHP

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

I am posting a XML file using the http post method.
I have uses the [following links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php) for that

How can I get a response in PHP.

I thinks [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Response_codes#200) will be better to understand.

I have required, if server response is 200 then ok, I will delete the xml file from the folder, If the server response is other then 200, I will retry http post to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have done the following code for the solution:**

Please Follow the link regarding the code.

I have used [$http_response_header](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php)

- http://rahulitjec.blogspot.in/2014/08/getting-success-response-for-posting.html